# CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, masking, cgimage, ciimage

I have a view with black text around which I want to create a white "glow". I figure I can do this by grabbing a screenshot, inverting the colors (it's only black and white), masking the black to transparent, then "jittering" the resulting image in each direction. When I try to mask the black with CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors I get a null CGImageRef. So far this is what I have.

```
//First get a screenshot into a CI image so I can apply a CI Filter
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
CIImage* ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() CGImage]];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Now apply the CIColorInvert filter
CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, ciImage, nil];
ciImage = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

//Now I need to get a CG image from the CI image.
CIContext* ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef ref = [ciContext createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:[ciImage extent]];

//Now I try to mask black
const float maskingColor[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
ref = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(ref, maskingColor); //ref is (null)
```

I know alpha channels can muck up the works but I really don't think I have any alpha channels here. Just to check I did `CGImageGetColorSpace(ref)` and got `kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB`, no alpha channel.

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong? Optionally, a quick comment helping me understand the differences between UIImage, CIImage and CGImage would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for `CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors` describes the `image` parameter as:

> The image to mask. This parameter may not be an image mask, may
>   not already have an image mask or masking color associated with it,
>   and **cannot have an alpha component**.

You should use `CGImageGetAlphaInfo` to determine if your CGImageRef has an alpha channel.

And in terms of getting rid of that pesky alpha channel, I think you'll find this SO question helpful:

[CGBitmapContextCreate with kCGImageAlphaNone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408292/cgbitmapcontextcreate-with-kcgimagealphanone)

Comment: Thanks, `CGImageGetAlphaInfo(ref)` returned `1`.
I then tried `const CGFloat maskingColor[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};` but I'm still getting (null).

Comment: Which is `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`, which means you have an alpha channel.

Comment: See my edits above.  That alpha channel is definitely going to cause you some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, there may be a better way of doing this but this works!

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithChromaKeyMasking {
    const CGFloat colorMasking[6]={255.0,255.0,255.0,255.0,255.0,255.0};
    CGImageRef oldImage = self.CGImage;
    CGBitmapInfo oldInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(oldImage);
    CGBitmapInfo newInfo = (oldInfo & (UINT32_MAX ^ kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask)) | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(oldImage);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGImageCreate(self.size.width, self.size.height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(oldImage), CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(oldImage), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(oldImage), CGImageGetColorSpace(oldImage), newInfo, provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider); provider = NULL;
    CGImageRef im = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(newImage, colorMasking);
    UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:im];
    CGImageRelease(im);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: it's not working I am trying to change grey pixel to blue pixel how do I achieve with your code